# Should I tell my employer about my new starter company

Tags: interviewing, conflict-of-interest

I have started my own company (i am the only employee in it) and trying to find customers/investors for my new business

it is Computer Solutions for healthcare.

is it a plus to mention that in a job interview?

Do I have to tell my employer that I am doing that on my own time (in case my employer is in healthcare and in the case my employer is in another industry)?

is it a conflict of interest?

Comment: hey @asmgx I strongly believe that your question has been asked before and is answered by the ones I linked as duplicates... if you disagree, please comment why and why it's not a duplicate or why it does not answer your question, or well post a [meta-tag:reopen-request] on our Meta site... or ping me

Comment: @DarkCygnus my case is specific to the healthcare sector. so i think it is a bit different that other mentioned before

Comment: the fact that your case is healthcare sector does not mean that the others don't answer your query. Conflict of interest, "if you should disclose", etc, apply to any industry. In other words, imagine having a post like this for each and every possible industry... not quite ok right? The core question and answer is the conflict of interest, regardless of industry (I'd say "canonical" but I don't want to stretch that word).

Comment: @asmgx - unless there are specific regulatory, duty-to-disclose requirements in the Healthcare sector in your country (that would also be something that would cause a question to be closed - we can't answer specific legal questions), then the other questions should provide answers.